# Application stops unexpectedly after few beeps

Tags: android

I have written a code for an app which gives a beep when phone is tilted at certain angle. It works fine at start but when I tilt phone 7th or 8th time onwards, it stops giving beep any further. When i check application status, it is shown as running. My code for the Service is

```
public class TheService extends Service implements SensorEventListener {
    public static final String TAG = TheService.class.getName();
    public static final int SCREEN_OFF_RECEIVER_DELAY = 500;

    private SensorManager mSensorManager = null;
    private WakeLock mWakeLock = null;
    private float lastY;

    MediaPlayer mp1;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;


    /*
     * Register this as a sensor event listener.
     */
    private void registerListener() {
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this,
                mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    /*
     * Un-register this as a sensor event listener.
     */
    private void unregisterListener() {
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    public BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onReceive("+intent+")");

            if (!intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
                return;
            }

            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Runnable executing.");
                    unregisterListener();
                    registerListener();
                }
            };

            new Handler().postDelayed(runnable, SCREEN_OFF_RECEIVER_DELAY);
        }
    };

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {


        Log.i(TAG, "onAccuracyChanged().");


    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onSensorChanged().");

        lastY = event.values[2];

        if (lastY  <9  && lastY > 8) {   
        mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.help);


        mMediaPlayer.start(); 


        }    


        }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

        PowerManager manager =
            (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        mWakeLock = manager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);

        registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

    mMediaPlayer.release();
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        unregisterListener();
        mWakeLock.release();
        stopForeground(true);


    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        startForeground(Process.myPid(), new Notification());
        registerListener();
        mWakeLock.acquire();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

}
```

My code for main activity is

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String TAG = HelpIMFalling.class.getName();


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        startService(new Intent(this, TheService.class));

    }
        }
```

I am not sure if android is killing it or there is any problem in my code. Had Android been doing that, the app would not have been shown as running in background. Kindly help.

Comment: I do not know how to check that !! can you plz guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any logs?

Avoid recreating the MediaPlayer:

```
if(mMediaPlayer == null)
  mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.help);
```

Comment: Its working fine now. Thanks a lot itechevo. One more query; since I am using wakelock so that my app gives beep even if phone is in standby mode ( screen off) , would it drain battery a lot??

Comment: Yes, it will drain the battery. From [Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html) - Always make sure to disable sensors you don't need, especially when your activity is paused. Failing to do so can drain the battery in just a few hours. Note that the system will not disable sensors automatically when the screen turns off.